# Webform radio buttons - why would they differ in appearance between two sites on a multi-site installation?

Tags: webforms, theming

I have several sites in a multi-site installation, and at least three of them have Webform enabled.  On one site, radio buttons in forms display like this:

0 Choice A 
0 Choice B
0 Choice C

That site uses the Garland theme.

One a second site, running on a proprietary theme called Nevia, radio buttons look like this:

0
Choice A

0
Choice B

0
Choice C

Any idea where to start changing the CSS to make the Nevia version behave like in Garland?  I don't know which stylesheet controls this.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to know which stylesheet is doing it and you shouldn't change the base sheet anyway. Create your own stylesheet to override the default CSS and make sure it is included after the standard theme style sheets.

Comment: Why: Because they're different themes. Have you used the web inspector on your browser? It tells you where each CSS declaration's coming from, which file and what line.